# Highlighting multiple rows in excel based on a specific cell's text

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a excel sheet question that I would like help on. My problem is that I am trying to highlight rows based on the specific text of "special audits" that I have listed in my column D but I would also like to highlight the multiple other rows from that same account number (column A) regardless if those rows have "special audits" in them.

Using conditional formatting does the highlighting of the rows of "special audits" but I can not figure out how to highlight the other rows from the same account. My sample sheet has 4 columns and 37 rows. Column A has numerical account numbers, Column B has the last name of the client, Column C has the date of the audit, and Column D has the type of the audit. Each client has multiple rows of audits and the account number is specific to the clients last name.

[image: My sample excel sheet image]

I thought that once I highlighted the "special audit" rows from column D then I could do another new conditional formatting rule for column A based on the cell's highlighted color. The conditional format rule that I have and works for just the one criteria that I have is  **=$D1="Special Audits"**

Comment: @Notice_Panda Your solution worked.Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, not sure why you removed the checkmark but I'm glad it worked. Just so you know, if you misspell the name, the person you're tagging doesn't get notified :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Countifs should do it for you:

[image]

The formula used:

> =COUNTIFS($D:$D,"Special Audits",$A:$A,$A2)>0

This basically says: Color if there's at least one cell in D-column with "Special Audits" that has the same A-column value.

Comment: The formula that you gave does work but I noticed on my sheet it missed a single row at the bottom of each account. I modified the formula to read =COUNTIFS($D:$D,"Special Audits",$A:$A,$A1)>0 .....changed $A2 to $A1 and that corrected my sheet.

Comment: That's just a matter of where you started to select from, I assume you started on row1 hence you needing $A1 instead of $A2 :) (that's why I usually show the range I selected and "Applies to" in my screenshots)

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling and I thought the check mark took when I clicked it but I may have double clicked it. Check mark has now been reinstated. You are correct on the $A position. Thank you again. Is there a trick/formula on mass deleting the highlighted rows by color?

Comment: Sort by color and then delete would be the fastest since excel prefers to have them in a big chunk instead of having to delete (and shift up) row by row